# XML Deserialization doesn't work

Tags: c#, xml

```
public class PersistableObject
    {
        public static T Load<T>(string fileName) where T : PersistableObject, new()
        {
            T result = default(T);

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
            {
                result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader) as T;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public void Save<T>(string fileName) where T : PersistableObject
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(stream, this);
            }
        }
    }

public class DatabaseConfiguration : PersistableObject
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I load the XML using the following code:

```
var configuration = PersistableObject.Load<DatabaseConfiguration>("Database.xml");
```

However, configuration's properties are null. This is Database.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DatabaseConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <Host>localhost</Host>
  <Schema>chromium</Schema>
  <Username>root</Username>
  <Password></Password>
</DatabaseConfiguration>
```

They stay null for some reason and are not assigned anything. Why's that?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Database.xml` content is incorrect, specifically its second line that closes the `DatabaseConfiguration` element.

Replace it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DatabaseConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <Host>localhost</Host>
  <Schema>chromium</Schema>
  <Username>root</Username>
  <Password></Password>
</DatabaseConfiguration>
```